# XCode: can't select/create auto managed Apple Distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm a noob to react native ios and trying to upload my app to Testflight, I changed scheme to Release and in Build settings I changed it from Apple developemt -> Apple distribution, however when I try to archive the app I get this error:

```
app has conflicting provisioning settings.
app is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity Apple Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "Apple Development" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTrgw.jpg

Build settings screen (all checked to Apple Distribution):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpKyk.png

I tried to uncheck auto manage signing but then I can't choose any Distribution certificate or profiling even when I have one, is it not possible to let Xcode manage distribution certificates (only development)?

It works well with Apple development, why I can't do the same for Apple distribution??